# How can I run macos High Sierra in Linux using Qemu?

Tags: linux, macos, iso-image, bootable-media

How can I run macos High Sierra in Linux using Qemu?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the macos High Sierra install app? Does it create stand-alone iso's from the running system, or generic iso's you could download from somewhere else? Does it run in linux?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a bootable disk image file that boots macOS High Sierra, but it doesn’t have to be an actual ISO format disk image, right? I ask because typically bootable macOS disk images are .dmg files, not ISO files. So I figured you were using “ISO” in the generic sense of a disk image file, not specifically requiring the actual ISO format.

Comment: The macos HIgh Sierra download app is the full High Sierra operating system and is used to install High Sierra on a mac. However, it doesn't appear to be recognized by virtualization software, whereas an ISO would be.

Comment: Check out the answers to this similar question, it may be of some help. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120962/making-a-bootable-usb-os-x-installer-from-iso-on-linux